# Call an Asynchronous call in a function with return

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm trying to include a library in my Android project which is used to show a calendar and populate it with Items.

The calendar gets populated with a listener which looks like this:

```
public List<Event> onMonthChanged(int month, int year) {
     //get Events
     return eventlist;
}
```

My problem is that I want to get the events from an asynchronous method, so the result is only available delayed. Because of this I can't immediately send a return back to the function.

How can I delay the return until the result of the asynchronous request is here without freezing the whole app?

Comment: A better answer would be to find some other API to supply events to the calendar. That may require a different calendar implementation. The author of this calendar apparently expects you to have all events cached in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Handler` and send `emptyMessage`  It will not stop your execution and won't freeze app.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how the OP will deliver `List<Event>` to the calendar by using your approach.